# How to make the output of OS.popen command a list of choice menu?

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-os

How to make the output of `os.popen` a list of choice menu options which will be used as input for another program?

Note - Every time the output varies we cannot define one constant choice menu. It can be more than 10 or sometimes less than 10 elements.

```
SG = "dzdo symaccess -sid {0} show {1} view -detail"
IG = os.popen SG).read()
print SG
```

Above is the program if the output of `SG` has some ten elements like below:

```
tiger
lion
elephant
deer
pigeon
fox
hyena
leopard
cheatah
hippo
```

The above elements I want to make as choice of elements like:

```
print("1. tiger")
print("2. lion")
print("3. elephant")
print("4. deer")
.
.
.
print("11. exit")
print ("\n")
choice = input('enter your choice [1-11] :')
choice = int(choice)
if choice ==1:
    ...
```

So how do we add each element in each print statement and make it have a choice option, and how can we know the number of elements and make the same number of choices menu?

Comment: Yee, why are you still using python 2, as far as I know the popen itself is deprecated even in python 3. We use instead subprocess module

Comment: You need to seriously think about moving to Python 3, Python 2.6 support ended ages ago, and Python 2.7 will reach its official End of Life in 2020. But if you're currently stuck on 2.6 you can still use `subprocess` instead of `popen`.

Comment: However, your question isn't totally clear. You need to show us what the output of the `SG` program actually looks like. BTW, it's not a good idea to use `input` on Python 2, it's a big security hole, use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Our company is still using 2.6 ,  to update it to 3 it is not possible now. I have already have a program with os.popen to extend this programme I have to continue with os.popen. The out put of SG I have given above as tiger, lion etc....

Comment: Do you mean that `os.popen(SG).read()` returns a one line string like `"tiger, lion, elephant, deer, pigeon, fox, hyena, leopard, cheetah, hippo"`?

Comment: the output will be a list line by line.  i.e each line one animal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously I can't demonstrate the `popen` stuff, so I've hard-coded the input data into a multi-line string, which I turn into a list using the `.splitlines` method. This code will cope with data of any size, it's not restricted to 10 items.

It does some primitive checking of the user input, a real program should display a more helpful message than 'Bad choice'.

```
from __future__ import print_function

IG = '''\
tiger
lion
elephant
deer
pigeon
fox
hyena
leopard
cheatah
hippo
'''

data = IG.splitlines()
for num, name in enumerate(data, 1):
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(num, name))

exitnum = num + 1
print('{0}: {1}'.format(exitnum, 'exit'))
while True:
    choice = raw_input('Enter your choice [1-{0}] : '.format(exitnum))
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
        if not 1 <= choice <= exitnum:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('Bad choice')
        continue
    if choice == exitnum:
        break
    elif choice == 1:
        print('Tigers are awesome')
    else:
        print('You chose {0}'.format(data[choice-1]))

print('Goodbye')
```

**demo output**

```
1: tiger
2: lion
3: elephant
4: deer
5: pigeon
6: fox
7: hyena
8: leopard
9: cheatah
10: hippo
11: exit
Enter your choice [1-11] : 3
You chose elephant
Enter your choice [1-11] : c
Bad choice
Enter your choice [1-11] : 1
Tigers are awesome
Enter your choice [1-11] : 12
Bad choice
Enter your choice [1-11] : 4
You chose deer
Enter your choice [1-11] : 11
Goodbye
```

Tested on Python 2.6.6. This code will also work correctly on Python 3, you just need to change `raw_input` to `input` for Python 3. But *please* don't use `input` on Python 2.

Comment: when I used the same script  in python 3.5 I am getting only the last one i.e. only hippo and exit in choice menu. In 3.5.2 do I need to change any thing. I changed raw_input to input in 3.5.2

Comment: @kalyanyellapu Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. The code behaves as expected on Python 3, once `raw_input` is changed to `input`.